# variance_scaling_initializer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distribution'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

Here i want to predict the same values with time (regression neural network) using python. Here I have two outputs with three inputs. when I run the code it gives me an error "variance_scaling_initializer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distribution'". Can you help me to solve the problem.?
Here I upload my code,

```js
n_neurons_1 = 24
n_neurons_2 = 12
n_target = 2
softmax = 2
weight_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(mode= "FAN_AVG", distribution ="uniform", scale = softmax)
bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
w_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_time_dimensions,n_neurons_1]))
bias_hidden_1= tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_1]))
w_hidden_2= tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_1,n_neurons_2]))
bias_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_2]))
w_out = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_2,2]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([2]))

                        
hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w_hidden_1),bias_hidden_1))
hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w_hidden_2),bias_hidden_2))

out = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_2, w_out),bias_out))
```

My dataset is,

```js
date        time g    p c apparentg
6/8/2018 0:06:15 141 131 136 141
6/8/2018 0:09:25 95 117 95 95
6/8/2018 0:11:00 149 109 139 149
6/8/2018 0:13:50 120 103 95 120
6/8/2018 0:16:20 135 97 105 135
6/8/2018 0:19:00 63 NaN 97 63
6/8/2018 0:20:00 111 NaN 100 111
6/8/2018 0:22:10 115 NaN 115 115
6/8/2018 0:23:40 287 NaN NaN 287
```

error is,

```js
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-9ceeb97429b1> in <module>()
     31 n_target = 2
     32 softmax = 2
---> 33 weight_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(mode= "FAN_AVG", distribution ="uniform", scale = softmax)
     34 bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
     35 w_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_time_dimensions,n_neurons_1]))

TypeError: variance_scaling_initializer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distribution'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into Documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/variance_scaling_initializer

```
tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
    factor=2.0,
    mode='FAN_IN',
    uniform=False,
    seed=None,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
```

and

```
uniform: Whether to use uniform or normal distributed random initialization.
```

So try

```
uniform = True
```

instead of

```
distribution ="uniform"
```

in your function call

```
 tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(mode= "FAN_AVG", distribution ="uniform", scale = softmax)
```

also there seems to be no `scale=` attribute in that function.